# How is precedence grouping implemented in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I've been looking through the SQLAlchemy api and it's incredibly complex, so I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone can explain this to me in a somewhat digestable format.

I'm writing a wrapper around the O365 python api for writing Office365 REST api queries with a syntax similar to SQLAlchemy.

O365 offers a fluent query class, like so:

```
Message.new_query().on_attribute("subject").contains("Hello Friend!").chain("and").on_attribute("from").equals("some_address@gmail.com")
```

And I've currently got something that works and looks like this:

```
Message.where(Subject.contains("Hello Friend!") & (From == "some_address@gmail.com")).execute()
```

The exact code isn't really relevant, but briefly, it builds up BooleanExpression objects by implementing magic methods for operators and adding extra methods such as .contains(). for example:

```
From == "some_address@gmail.com"
```

would return a BooleanExpression.

BooleanExpression objects are then combined with the "&" or "|" operators returning BooleanExpressionClause objects, which are basically a list of BooleanExpression objects that keeps track of which operator every 2 expressions are joined by.

At the end, the .where() method consumes a single BooleanExpressionClause and builds up a fluent query for it under the hood.

So far so good.

So the roadblock I've hit involves precedence grouping.

Let's say I wanted all messages with "Hi!" in their subject by either senders who have "john" in their address, or "doe" in their address. If I had a query like this:

```
From.contains("john") | From.contains("doe") & Subject.contains("Hi!")
```

I would get every single message from anyone with "john" in their address, because Microsoft's API actually reads the resulting REST request as:

```
From.contains("john") | (From.contains("doe") & Subject.contains("Hi!"))
```

When what I want is:

```
(From.contains("john") | From.contains("doe")) & Subject.contains("Hi!")
```

However, if I simply wrote that using my current API, it would be no different from just writing it without any parentheses at all, because as far as I can tell, to python, the first example (with no precedence groups), and the third example (with the precedence groups I want) look exactly the same since the interpreter just reads a clause like this from left to right anyway.

That finally brings me to my question. SQLAlchemy is capable of understanding precedence groups somehow, but I can't for the life of me understand how it does it.

For example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import engine, Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, String

engine = engine("some_engine_url")
Base = declarative_base()
s = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name          = Column(String)
    sex           = Column(String(1))

print(s.query(Person).filter( (Person.name == "john") | (Person.name == "doe") & (Person.sex == "M") ))
print(s.query(Person).filter( ((Person.name == "john") | (Person.name == "doe")) & (Person.sex == "M") ))
```

These print statements return, respectively,

```
SELECT person.id AS person_id, person.name AS person_name, person.sex AS person_sex 
FROM person 
WHERE person.name = ? OR person.name = ? AND person.sex = ?
```

and

```
SELECT person.id AS person_id, person.name AS person_name, person.sex AS person_sex 
FROM person 
WHERE (person.name = ? OR person.name = ?) AND person.sex = ?
```

How in the world can the SQLAlchemy internals tell the difference between these two filter clauses? As far as I can tell, python should be processing them identically, but clearly there's some magic going on there somewhere that I'm unaware
of.

How can I replicate this behaviour?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> That finally brings me to my question. SQLAlchemy is capable of understanding precedence groups somehow, but I can't for the life of me understand how it does it.

SQLAlchemy does not have to do much work here. Most of the work is done by Python, which parses objects in a specific order. Python parses expressions according to the rules of [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), and so executes the combined expressions in a specific order based on precedence. If that order of precedence is correct for your application, and don't mind about *always* grouping nested expressions, you are set. That's not always the case in SQL, and SQLAlchemy wants to output valid SQL expressions with minimal extraneous parenthesis use, so SQLAlchemy does consult a precedence table of its own. That way it can decide when `(...)` grouping is required in the output.

SQLAlchemy returns dedicated `*Clause*` expression objects representing the operation on its operands (each of which can be further expressions), and then combines those further when those operation objects are also used in operations. In the end, you'd have a *tree* of objects, and traversal of that tree during compilation to SQL then produces the grouped output you see, as needed. Where precedence requires it, SQLAlchemy does insert [`sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Grouping()` objects](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/26ef5ed862270bda4ab6abe544add9f8bb7ac72f/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py#L3330-L3370), and it is up to the SQL dialect to produce the right syntax for grouping.

If you are looking at the SQLAlchemy source code, you'll want to look at the [`sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators` class](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py#L297-L1152) and it's parent class, [`sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py#L42-L238), which [implements `__or__`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py#L83-L105) as a call to `self.operate(or_, other)` (passing in the [`operator.or_()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.or_)). In SQLAlchemy this appears complicated, because this has to delegate to different types of comparisons for different types of objects and SQL dialects!

But at the base is the [`sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator` module](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py), where `or_` and `and_` are (indirectly) mapped to classmethods of [`sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BooleanClauseList`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py#L2011-L2144), producing an instance of that class.

The [`BooleanClauseList._construct()` method](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/26ef5ed862270bda4ab6abe544add9f8bb7ac72f/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py#L2024-L2057) is responsible for handling grouping there, by delegating to `.self_group()` methods on the two clauses:

```
convert_clauses = [
    c.self_group(against=operator) for c in convert_clauses
]
```

This passes in `operator.or_` or `operator.and_`, and so lets each operand decide if they need to use a `Grouping()` instance, based on precedence. For `BooleanClauseList` objects (so the result of `... | ...` or `... & ...` but then *combined* with another `|` or `&` operator), the [`ClauseList.self_group()` method](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/26ef5ed862270bda4ab6abe544add9f8bb7ac72f/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py#L2003-L2008) will produce a `Grouping()` if `self.operator` has a lower or equal precedence compared to `against`:

```
def self_group(self, against=None):
    # type: (Optional[Any]) -> ClauseElement
    if self.group and operators.is_precedent(self.operator, against):
        return Grouping(self)
    else:
        return self
```

where [`sqlalchemy.sql.operators.is_precedent()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/26ef5ed862270bda4ab6abe544add9f8bb7ac72f/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py#L1496-L1502) consults an expression precedence table:

```
_PRECEDENCE = {
    # ... many lines elided

    and_: 3,
    or_: 2,

    # ... more lines elided
}

def is_precedent(operator, against):
    if operator is against and is_natural_self_precedent(operator):
        return False
    else:
        return _PRECEDENCE.get(
            operator, getattr(operator, "precedence", _smallest)
        ) <= _PRECEDENCE.get(against, getattr(against, "precedence", _largest))
```

So what happens for your two expressions? **Python** has picked up the `()` parentheses grouping. Lets first simplify the expressions to the base components, you basically have:

```
A | B & C
(A | B) & C
```

Python parses these two expressions according to its own precedence rules, and produces its own *abstract syntax tree*:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('A | B & C', mode='eval').body)
"BinOp(left=Name(id='A', ctx=Load()), op=BitOr(), right=BinOp(left=Name(id='B', ctx=Load()), op=BitAnd(), right=Name(id='C', ctx=Load())))"
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('(A | B) & C', mode='eval').body)
"BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Name(id='A', ctx=Load()), op=BitOr(), right=Name(id='B', ctx=Load())), op=BitAnd(), right=Name(id='C', ctx=Load()))"
```

These come down to

```
BinOp(
    left=A,
    op=or_,
    right=BinOp(left=B, op=and_, right=C)
)
```

and

```
BinOp(
    left=BinOp(left=A, op=or_, right=B),
    op=and_,
    right=C
)
```

which changes the order in which objects are combined! So the first leads to:

```
# process A, then B | C

leftop = A
rightop = BooleanClauseList(and_, (B, C))

# combine into A & (B | C)
final = BooleanClauseList(or_, (leftop, rightop))

# which is
BooleanClauseList(or_, (A, BooleanClauseList(and_, (B, C))))
```

Because the second clause here is a `BooleanClauseList(and_, ...)` instance, the `.self_group()` call for that clause doesn't return a `Grouping()`; there `self.operator` is `and_`, which has a precedence of 3, which is higher, not lower or equal, to the precendence of `or_` == 2 for the parent clause.

The other expression is executed by Python in a different order:

```
# process A | B, then C

leftop = BooleanClauseList(or_, (A, B))
rightop = C

# combine into (A | B) & C
final = BooleanClauseList(and_, (leftop, rightop))

# which is
BooleanClauseList(and_, (BooleanClauseList(or_, (A, B)), C))
```

Now the first clause is a `BooleanClauseList(or_, ...)` instance, and it actually produces a `Grouping` instance because `self.operator` is `or_` and that has a lower precedence to `and_` from the parent clause list, and so the object tree becomes:

```
BooleanClauseList(and_, (Grouping(BooleanClauseList(or_, (A, B))), C))
```

Now, if all you want to do is ensure you have your expressions grouped in the right order, then you don't really need to inject your own `Grouping()` objects. It doesn't really matter if you process `and_(or_(A, B), C)` or `and_((or_(A, B)), C)` when you are processing the object tree by traversal, but if you need to output text again (like SQLAlchemy must, to send to the database) then the `Grouping()` objects are very helpful to record where you need to add `(...)` text.

In SQLAlchemy, that happens in the [SQL compiler](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py), which uses a [visitor pattern](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py) to call the [`sqlalchemy.sql.compiler.SQLCompiler.visit_grouping()` method](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py#L720-L721):

```
 def visit_grouping(self, grouping, asfrom=False, **kwargs):
     return "(" + grouping.element._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs) + ")"
```

That expression simply means: place `(` before, and `)` after, whatever the compilation output for `grouping.element` is. While each SQL dialect does provide a subclass of the base compiler, none override the `visit_grouping()` method.

Comment: Seriously, thanks so much! I can't believe how good and in-depth of an answer that was. I thought the & and | operators had equal precedence, and didn't think to check. Stupid.


Thanks for the dissection of the AST, and the explanation of the SQLAlchemy internals. I'm off to read about the visitor design pattern, whoo. This is probably a bit above my current programming proficiency in general but it's so freaking fascinating how intricate and well-structured a project like SQLAlchemy is. I feel like I can't even properly appreciate how brilliant the architecture is, but I really want to.